# Regex to find png-gif-jpg image links in HTML of CKeditor

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following regex to intercept posted image links in CKeditor:

```
var editorContent = String(qa_ckeditor_content.getData());
if( editorContent.match(/(https?:\/\/\S+\.(?:jpg|png|gif|jpg<br|png<br|gif<br|jpg<\/p>|png<\/p>|gif<\/p>))\s+/) != null ) {
    alert('Sorry, image links not allowed.');
    return false;
}
```

However, this will not find something like:

```
<a href="#">myimage.png</a>
```

I am trying to find the regex the looks for `png<...` (plus following characters). I tried that using a dot which seems not correct:

```
/(https?:\/\/\S+\.(?:jpg|png|gif|jpg<.|png<.|gif<.))\s+/
```

I know that this is a beginner question, but I failed finding the right solution :-(

Thank you for your time!

Comment: In `(?:jpg|png|gif|jpg<.|png<.|gif<.)`, the last 3 items will never be matched...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would like to point out the false security of blacklisting. There will always be that other case you didn't think of that makes it through.

That being said; you could just have the the regex search for .jpg, .png, .gif etc. followed by anything other than a word character.

```
/\.(jpg|png|gif)\b/
```

This will match those extensions in any case I can think of at least, and can replace that entire regex you have so far.

Comment: Thanks melwil, you are right. I can go over all text to find those 3 items. Let's see if it will work with my usecases :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
<a[^>]+>(.+?\.(?:jpg|png|gif))<
```

and a sample code:

```
match = inputString.match(/<a[^>]+>(.+?\.(?:jpg|png|gif))</);
if (match != null) {
    // matched text: match[0]
    file = match[1];
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```